# Auto login between word press subdomain and a .net website

Tags: login, wp-login-form

I am looking for a solution which can help me auto maintain login from my main website i.e. www.maybexyz.com to my sub domain which powers content for my website i.e. community.maybexyz.com.

My website is built using .net code and my community is powered through wordpress.

Any suggestions which can help.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are logged-in to main website then you can make an AJAX request to you WP server.

In AJAX request, it will be basically calling a function in functions.php and in that function use this method - `wp_set_auth_cookie` . ( [Read more](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie) )

So this method basically takes your username and password. I hope you are having the same username and password as that of your .NET application and WP application.

Comment: I will try this and will write back in case it doesn't work. Thank you so much for quick response.